# Scalability of database on an Amazon EC2 micro instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an elastic beanstalk application which is utilizing an EC2 micro instance.

On the EC2 instance I manually installed a mysql database.

The beanstalk application is accessing the database through localhost:3306.

My question is, how will the database scale if the beanstalk application load is increasing? Will I run into any problem with this setup? Should I migrate my application to use the Amazon RDS?

Answer (score 0):

If the load on your application increases the database on EC2 instance will not scale itself. It will fail if you do not take any steps. All you can do is vertical scaling. And you can have read replicas. The same is true for RDS. With RDS, DB server does not scale automatically, you need to upscale it your self if the traffic increases. So RDS decreases your DB management overhead.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. For Amazon RDS, what kind of upscale are you talking about? Like making the EC2 instance more powerful? Isn't that the same as vertical scaling in the first case?

Comment: Yes it is same. RDS offers easy maintenance of you DB, other than that it is actually DB on EC2 instances managed by Amazon. But you have to manually scale DB on RDS.

Answer (score 0):

Your application will run into a lot of issues on a micro. If this is in production, I recommend moving to a small ASAP. That being said, you can work the /etc/my.cnf file and do some pretty great things on a small instance. If/when you have to scale up from that it's a good problem to have.

Some good advice for running a database, is mount a dedicated EBS volume at /var/lib/mysql so you can move your database to new instances easily. If you're experiencing high traffic you'll want to either have enough memory in your instance to house the entire database, or if this is not possible, you'll want to optimize your EBS so that your IOPS threshold is met. This will give you the best performance you can get on AWS.